# get values from XML with xpath when having Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument

I am new to xpath matching. Here I have a method which pass XML contain as string. I convert it into XmlDocument.

```
public static void getProjectDataInfo(string content) {

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(content);
}
```

Here is my XML. It has xmlns:my

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:myFields xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46" xmlns:xd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003" xml:lang="en-us">
  <my:Financial>
      <my:Quote>
     <my:CHARGE_TYPE>MRC</my:CHARGE_TYPE>
     <my:Price>463.92</my:Price>
      </my:Quote>
  </my:Financial>
</my:myField>
```

I just want to get values of

```
/my:myFields/my:Financial/my:Quote/my:Price
```

However I unable to get values hence this XML has xmlns.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx)

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46");

var str = doc.XPathSelectElement("/root/ns:myFields/ns:Financial/ns:Quote/ns:Price", nsmgr)
            .ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: I think we can not get '/root/ns:myFields/ns:Financial/ns:Quote/ns:Price' at one time. Insterd of it I get part by part.

Comment: Yes. We need to get it element by element. I did not dare to execute it. It was a logical error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LINQ2XML`

```
XElement doc=XElement.Parse(content);
XNamespace my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46";
var price=doc.Element(my+"myFields").Element(my+"Financial").Element(my+"Quote").Element(my+"Price").Value;
```

---

**OR**[if you want to stick with that **OLD** thing]

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46");
var priceNode = el.SelectNode(@"/my:myFields/my:Financial/my:Quote/my:Price", nsmgr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the XmlDocument what `my` prefix binds to. You use XmlNamespaceManager to do that. Here is an example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316913. In your case you would do:

`xmlns.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2012-02-03T16:54:46")`

Answer (score 0):

For Infopath form 2013, it could be as following:

XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
                nsmgr.AddNamespace("my", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/infopath/2003/myXSD/2014-11-10T18:44:26");

XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

XmlNode yourIDNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/my:myFields/my:YourID", nsmgr);

The detail "my" namespace definition, you could download from Share Point Document Library where your infopath form submitted xml data staying. Download one of those saved infopath form xml data files, and open it with notepad, then you wll find it on the top of content.